# Highcharts' bullet graph's serie's doesn't extend all the way

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

When I set the serie's value equal to the of the plotBands,the graph extends itself making the serie's bar never reach the end of the graph.

```
...
yAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
        from: 0,
        to: 150,
        color: '#666'
    }, {
        from: 150,
        to: 225,
        color: '#999'
    }, {
        from: 225,
        to: 500,
        color: '#bbb'
    }],
    title: null
},
plotOptions: {

},
series: [{
    data: [{
        y: 500,
        target: 220
    }]
}],
....
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/m21d08Lv/

How can I stop this behaviour,so the serie's bar reach all the way to the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because when Highcharts automatically calculates extremes it adds some extra space between the point with the highest value and the plot area edge (visual reasons). To prevent this default behavior use `xAxis.max` property.

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0w330rae/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max